# How can I have an SQL query return an extra column with an arithmetic result in it?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My current query is

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM events, times 
WHERE events.email = '$email' 
and 
events.type = times.type";
```

events.date is a date in sql of form yyyy-mm-dd

times.time is a date in sql of the same form but 0000-mm-dd.

I want an extra column from my query with the recommended start dates for an event.

ie.  events.date - times.time

Can I have sql return an extra column that includes the recommended start dates?

or am I way off the mark?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

edit:

this is what I have now:

```
SELECT *, date_diff(events.date, times.time) AS recommended FROM events, times WHERE events.email = '$email' and events.type = times.type ORDER by events.date
```

from what I can tell it shouldn't fail, but it does.  it complains about my syntax.

edit:

it's working now, thanks

this is what I've got

```
$sql="SELECT *, date_format(events.date - times.time, '%Y-%m-%d') as recommended 
FROM events, times 
WHERE events.email = '$email' 
and 
events.type = times.type ORDER by events.date";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not off the mark at all. You can create an extra column and give it a name by doing your calculation and using an alias to name it.

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(events.date,times.time) AS recommended_start_date
FROM events, times;
```

I'm not sure if the TIMESTAMPDIFF function is the exact one you're looking for. Perhaps DATEDIFF() might be better. [This part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of the MySQL docs lists all the date-related functions that you can use.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't quite have it working.  it complains about sytax.  I have what I've got added to my question above.

Comment: Glad it's working now! Just for the record, one thing that I see that is wrong with the previous query is that it calls the function `date_diff`, when the actual name of it is `datediff`. All one word.